# Usage of aggregate functions in MarkLogic

Tags: aggregate-functions, marklogic

I have an XML like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
  <ticker> CSGN.VX </ticker>
  <stockExchange> NYSE </stockExchange>
  <stockDatas>
    <stockData>
      <date>2015-08-06</date>
      <closingPrice>140</closingPrice>
    </stockData>
    <stockData>
      <date>2015-08-07</date>
      <closingPrice>140.25</closingPrice>
    </stockData>
    <stockData>
      <date>2015-08-10</date>
      <closingPrice>140.75</closingPrice>
    </stockData>
  </stockDatas>
</doc>
```

And I will be having similar XMLs for different companies around different years. Now I want to search for documents which have the ticker as CSGN.VX for a particular time duration, so I use this query.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace search =  "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

search:search(
  'ticker:CSGN.VX AND (dateRange GE "2015-08-07" AND dateRange LE "2015-08-21")', 
  <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <constraint name="dateRange">
      <range type="xs:date" facet="false">
        <element ns="" name="date"/>
      </range>
    </constraint>
    <constraint name="ticker">
      <range type="xs:string" >
        <element ns="" name="ticker"/>
      </range>
    </constraint>
  </options>)
```

Is there a way where along with the document search, I can also get the closingPrice average for that particular time duration?

I just got a solution but i have a further query, i was looking for a way to implement this using java client API of Marklogic so is there a way to implement search:parse and search:values using Java Client API

I know one way to implement this is through MarklogicXCC API but i wanted to know if there is a way through which these functions can be run using Client API

Comment: I think the question of how to use this from Java is worth a new SO question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you have a range index on closingPrice you should be able to do something like this:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace search =  "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

let $query :=
  search:parse(
    'ticker:CSGN.VX AND (dateRange GE "2015-08-07" AND dateRange LE "2015-08-21")',

    <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
      <constraint name="dateRange">
        <range type="xs:date" facet="false">
           <element ns="" name="date"/>
        </range>
      </constraint>
      <constraint name="ticker">
        <range type="xs:string" >
           <element ns="" name="ticker"/>
        </range>
      </constraint>
    </options>,

    "search:query"
  )

return
  search:values(
    'closingPrice', 

    <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
      <values name="closingPrice">
        <range type="xs:double">
           <element ns="" name="closingPrice"/>
        </range>
        <aggregate apply="avg"/>
      </values>
    </options>,

    $query
  )
```

Note: I do recommend storing each stockData separately, otherwise the dateRange filter probably won't work as expected.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks @grtjn for the answer although there is a slight edit in your query in aggregate apply it should be 

       <aggregate apply="average"/>

Comment: I saw your edit request, and (since it was rejected) copied over the typo fix, and applied it myself. Thanks for reporting it!